# Django model constraint at least one field from two is not null or empty

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I added a constraint to the model but seems that it has no impact because I'm still able to create a model instance without supplying any of the fields. Please help me to enforce the constraint to check is at least one field from two is not null or empty.

Fields:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
   name1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
   name2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=(
                    Q(name1__isnull=False)
                    | Q(name2__isnull=False)
                    | ~Q(name1__exact='')
                    | ~Q(name2__exact='')
                ),
                name='color_names_not_null_or_empty'
            )
        ]
```

Django v4
Postgres v15

Comment: Why do you have both `blank=True` and `null=True` on your `CharField`? You have two possible values for no data now...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat believe me or not, but sometimes an empty string is a perfectly valid entry and not an indicator of missing input. In such cases NULL can be used for missing data only.

Comment: (though it's not the case here, given an attempt to use both interchangeably in the constraint)